# add data from different excel files using python

Tags: python

I had a code that work perfectly for 2 files. But now, I want to add several excel files but it's not working.

Here is my code :

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_excel('alex.xlsx', index_col=None, header=None)
b = pd.read_excel('blago.xlsx', index_col=None, header=None)
c = pd.read_excel('claude.xlsx', index_col=None, header=None)
d = pd.read_excel('cristian.xlsx', index_col=None, header=None)
e = pd.read_excel('eric.xlsx', index_col=None, header=None)
f = pd.read_excel('haou.xlsx', index_col=None, header=None)
g = pd.read_excel('iulian.xlsx', index_col=None, header=None)
h = pd.read_excel('luca.xlsx', index_col=None, header=None)
i = pd.read_excel('maricel.xlsx', index_col=None, header=None)
j = pd.read_excel('michel.xlsx', index_col=None, header=None)
k = pd.read_excel('noel.xlsx', index_col=None, header=None)
l = pd.read_excel('paul.xlsx', index_col=None, header=None)




z = a.add(b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, fill_value=0)

z.to_excel("z.xlsx")
```

Comment: try [pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html). It can combine a list of dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

The `add` function doesn't join two dataframes, it adds to the values in a dataframe. I suggest using `concat` instead and also using the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module to avoid a separate call for each individual file like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

a = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(file, index_col=None, header=None) for file in glob.glob('*.xlsx')], ignore_index = True)
a.fillna(0, inplace = True)
a.to_excel("a.xlsx")
```